# Are white star relics similar to artifacts?

Tags: hades-star

I haven't had the best luck with the new white stars and getting the relics. But can you research the relic you retrieve in the research station?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Fandom Wikia page about White Stars :

> Corporations fight to retrieve and claim "relics" that are generated by planets scattered across the system. Relics must be moved to a safe location by transports before they are able to be claimed for a corporation. Relics claimed for a corporation remain claimed and cannot be taken away. Relics will initially serve no purpose other than bragging rights, however relics are planned to act as a currency for corporation advantages.

So for now, no. In the future, maybe, it's not clear, but some articles on the internet tell the HS team has plans for future use of relics. What use, I don't know, maybe they even didn' yet make up their minds...

[Source](http://hades-star.wikia.com/wiki/Stars)

Answer (score 0):

Just found out,

You cannot research relics like artifacts. Relics disappear when your transport gets back from the white star and add to the total count for your corporation.